# Streaming server with automatic quality

Tags: streaming, media-server

Does anyone knows a media streaming server solution for streaming video/audio with automatic quality(depending on the client bandwidth).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Darwin Streaming Server can offer differently encoded versions of the same content. It uses HTTP Streaming so the streaming session can adapt to the bandwidth with each chunk. You need to provide the differently encoded versions so.

Comment: That's one solution i was thinking a about. But mac hardware costs too much.

Comment: You can run Darwin Streaming server on FreeBSD for example. You can install FreeBSD on any normal (CHEEP!) pc x86 (x64) hardware.

Comment: Exactly, the Version which is only running on MacOSX is the Quicktime Streaming Server, which is an extended commercial Version of the DSS. DSS can be run on pretty much everything Unix.

Comment: A little bit of troubles while compiling, but i think in production I'll use DSS.

Answer (score 1):

i would like to know if what you meant above is that Darwin streaming server can in someway switch from streaming one video file in another video file which has greater or less quality from the first one.Any help will be useful.Thank youu

Comment: No, DSS can detect the bandwidth of the client. If the bandwidth is big, the quality of the stream is high; if the bandwidth is small, the quality of the video stream will be small.

Comment: Yes,i understand what you are saying because it's something that you can see while the streaming is happening, whether you get high or small quality.I'm just trying to find a way to do what i have said in my first post.But thank you very much for answering.